# World changes not saved after editing in gazebo_ros (2.2.3)

Tags: ros

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm working in ROS (Indigo, Ubuntu 14), starting gazebo 2.2.3 with

```
rosrun gazebo_ros gazebo
```

I go in and create a little corner of a room by dropping in a couple of cubes and scaling them:

[image: image description]

I save the file as corner.world. Then later open it, and the scaling I did is gone:

[image: image description]

I've now just got two cubes. Where did the walls go?

I just cross posted this here:
http://answers.ros.org/question/242109/saving-changes-to-objects-in-gazebo_ros-world-file/

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/14206/world-changes-not-saved-after-editing-in-gazebo_ros-(2.2.3)/) by [neuronet](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2728/neuronet/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-08-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There were a few [issues](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/1567/incorrect-visual-geom-size-when-saving-a) scaling shapes and saving the world which have been fixed in newer versions of Gazebo. Since Gazebo 2 is [no longer](http://gazebosim.org/#status) officially supported, I suggest you change to the latest long term support version, Gazebo 7.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2016-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [neuronet](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2728/neuronet/) on 2016-08-21**:
Unfortunately this is what is built-in with ros, and gazebo 2.N is stuck with Ros Indigo (http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_wrapper_versions).  I a noob to Linux, Ros, and Gazebo, and while it is *possible* to upgrade to more recent, it won't be natural and you have to do work to make it work. Which will basically put me in install hell with 95% probability. Thanks for your answer.

**Comment by [neuronet](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2728/neuronet/) on 2016-08-21**:
My workaround in the time being will be to build walls out of cubes. Not sure why they have it this way--having what is basically an obsolete version of gazebo installing with an actively supported version of ROS? Oh well... [mustn't rage quit ROS, mustn't rage quit ROS....]